# URL Rewrite fails without trailing slash, also would appreciate recommended tweaks for speed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm configuring URL Rewrite on IIS 8 and have it mostly working. I'm not too experienced with this stuff so I need help with one thing that's not working correctly and would love to hear some feedback on what else to modify to make it better, faster, etc.

folder structure:
/web data/ABC (contains CMS system)
/web data/deptOne
/web data/deptTwo
/web data/deptThree

(Each dept folder contains a single index.php file that contains a few simple CMS fields and points to ABC system directory.)

```
<rule name="ABC depts" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(deptOne|deptTwo|deptThree)/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(css|scripts|images|js|inc)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/index.php?/{R:1}/{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="ABC" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(/ABC/ABC_system|/ABC/themes|/ABC/admin.php)" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(css|scripts|images|js|inc)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="ABC/index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

**What's not working:**
If a trailing slash is left off of the main department URL it fails to load the correct dept page but loads the default ABC page instead.

fails:
example.com/deptone
(note it's a dept main page without a trailing slash)

works:
example.com/ABC
example.com/ABC/services/stuff
example.com/deptone/
example.com/deptone/services/stuff

The order of the two rules affects whether it works or not as well. That's why I have it ordered as is. Also, what can be changed to make it perform as well as possible? (speed, reliability)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `match` element I would use this pattern:

```
^(deptOne|deptTwo|deptThree)(/.*)?$
```

This requires that if any characters appear after the department name then a forward-slash must appear before those characters (so that deptOneExtra is not matched, for example).

Note that (if anything appears after the department name) the sequence captured by the second capture group will start with the forward-slash. This can be easily removed by taking a sub-string of the captured sequence, but if you really don't want to capture the forward-slash this might work:

```
^(deptOne|deptTwo|deptThree)(?:/(.*))?$
```

In regex the `(?:` syntax means "non-capturing group" and allows you to define a group without capturing the content it matches. So the second capture group should capture only the characters which come after the forward-slash, and not the forward-slash itself.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
^(deptOne|deptTwo|deptThree)/(.*)$
```

to:

```
^(deptOne|deptTwo|deptThree)/?(.*)$
```

and that seems to have fixed the trailing slash problem. (added question mark after the slash)

If anyone has any suggestions for improving its performance overall (both rules) then that would be appreciated.

Comment: Bear in mind that your new pattern will match "deptOneExtra" and split this (single) directory name into two pieces, tricking you into thinking you have received a request for "deptOne/Extra" when this is not the case.